# Count multiple status by day in the last X days

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by

I'm trying to make a query to count multiple status by day in the last X days.
I can make the query to count those but the output is nothing what I would like to be, maybe I have an error in my GROUP BY statement. So that's what I have right now:

Example Table:

```
date - status
02-12-2015 - 1
02-12-2015 - 1
02-12-2015 - 3
02-12-2015 - 2
03-12-2015 - 1
03-12-2015 - 2
```

My query:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( crdate , "%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S" ) , "%d-%m-%y" ) as date , COUNT(*) as countone
FROM TBL_NAME
WHERE status='1'
UNION
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( crdate , "%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S" ) , "%d-%m-%y" ) as date , COUNT(*) as counttwo
FROM TBL_NAME
WHERE status='2'
UNION
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( crdate , "%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S" ) , "%d-%m-%y" ) as date , COUNT(*) as countthree
FROM TBL_NAME
WHERE status='3'
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( crdate , "%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S" ) , "%d-%m-%y" ), status ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT( STR_TO_DATE( crdate , "%d-%m-%Y %H:%i:%S" ) , "%d-%m-%y" ) ASC
```

It's supposed the following output:

```
date - countone - counttwo - countthree
02-12-2015 - 2 - 1 - 1
03-12-2015 - 1 - 1 - 0
```

The problem  is that my output it's only being grouped by date.
My output is the following:

```
date - countone
02-12-2015 - 2
02-12-2015 - 1
02-12-2015 - 1
03-12-2015 - 1
03-12-2015 - 1
```

Anyone could help me achieving this? What I'm getting wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by first calculating the count of status using group by and then pivoting the table to get the desired result. Union function would be always concatenating rows.

```
select datefield,
    max(if(status=1,count,0)) as countone,
    max(if(status=2,count,0)) as counttwo,
    max(if(status=3,count,0)) as countthree
from (select datefield, status, count(*) as count
        from TBL_NAME
        group by datefield,status) A
group by datefield;
```

Checkout the SQL fiddle setup for it [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f590a/3)